# Unable to start Simulator in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I am writing a Windows Store App for Windows 8.1 in Visual Studio 2013 Premium and came across the following error when attempting to debug my application in the simulator:

```
Unable to start the Simulator. Another user on this computer is running Simulator, can not start Simulator.
```

Up until that point I was able to debug the application in the simulator without problems. I tried rebooting to make sure there wasn't an instance of the simulator stuck open somewhere, but that didn't help. Also, I am the only user on the computer so nobody else would have run Visual Studio.

I am still able to debug to my local machine, but that leaves me unable to test the behavior of my application when the screen is rotated. Any assistance in resolving this matter is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by repairing my installation of Visual Studio. Thank you for the assistance everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Simulator uses the remote desktop session. You can check if remote desktop is activated on your computer (and not blocked by a firewall rule), and try to launch VS as an administrator.

Comment: I was able to resolve the problem by repairing Visual Studio, but I really don't want to have to do that frequently! The next time this problem comes up I'll check remote desktop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My solutions:

1. **SignOut** and SignIn (using your **password not PIN**) :: then check if it
   works
2. Go to `System Properties > Remote` then check `Allow Remote Access...` and turn on `Allow Remote connections to computer` ::
       then check if it works
3. Still facing error?! go for **Repair**